# How can I update the GUI with live results from a for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am using for loop in my c# project.

I some cases I am iterating over 500,000 values - the GUI does not respond until the end of the loop.

Can I get the GUI to update inside the `for` loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    double s1 = rnd.NextDouble();
    double s2 = rnd.NextDouble();
    w = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(s1)) * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * s2);
    listBox1.Items.Add(w.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Put some code over here. Also are you talking about Web Application or Windows application.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to update the loop count to a Label?

Comment: Yes i want see dynamic loop count on label.

Comment: A listbox with 100000 items is unusable, and you should not be doing a loop inside your GUI. Instead of showing us what you are doing, tell us what you want to accomplish with your app because what you are doing makes no sense.

Comment: have you tried a refresh, like listBox1.Refresh();

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If it is single-threaded application you can get froze of you GUI. Try use Application.DoEvents() method in loop. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    labelToShow.Text = i.ToString(); // live update of information on the GUI
    labelToShow.Invalidate();
    Application.DoEvents();

    double s1 = rnd.NextDouble();
    double s2 = rnd.NextDouble();
    w = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(s1)) * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * s2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have done this is by starting a thread to populate a control item with text for that you would need to call a method from inside the thread to populate the listbox and that requires a delegate method,

Declare a delegate method in your class,

```
delegate void SetListBoxDelg(string value);
```

then start a thread that will start this process of populating the listbox,

```
Thread t  = new Thread(StartProc);
   t.Start();
```

this is the thread code where you call the method to populate your listbox,

```
public void StartProc()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  {
    double s1 = rnd.NextDouble();
    double s2 = rnd.NextDouble();
    w = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(s1)) * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * s2);
    SetListBox(w.ToString());
  }
}
```

And here is the method that is called from inside of the thread,

```
private void SetListBox(string value)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    SetListBoxDelg dlg = new SetListBoxDelg(this.SetListBox);
    this.Invoke(value);
    return;
  }
  listBox1.Items.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: This is basically correct. I might recommend Task.Run instead of a plain thread, and (if you're in WPF) you can also usually guiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(action) to make sure its updated on the right thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
      {
            label.Text = i;
            double s1 = rnd.NextDouble();
            double s2 = rnd.NextDouble();
            w = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(s1)) * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * s2);
            listBox1.Items.Add(w.ToString());

       }
```

Replace label.Text with your label's name.

Comment: No, if i use this code. I will see 100,000 on label. But i want see instant number of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Jason Hughes answered this above.  Use the Refresh() of the control you are displaying your counter in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    labelIteration.Text = i.ToString();
    labelIteration.Refresh();

    double s1 = rnd.NextDouble();
    double s2 = rnd.NextDouble();
    w = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(s1)) * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * s2);
}
```